# Snowflake create storage for s3

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to create integration storage for amazon s3 bucket:

```
create or replace storage integration s3_int
  type = external_stage
  storage_provider = s3
  enabled = true
  storage_aws_role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::127343226411:role/S3_Full_Access'
  storage_allowed_locations = ('s3://aaa.my.name.test/');
```

But i get an error:

```
SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on account 'NL71756'
```

What should i set up to correct it?

Comment: What role are you using when you run this create statement and does it have the required privileges?

Answer (score 1):

You need the appropriate permissions to create a storage stage:

> Only account administrators (users with the ACCOUNTADMIN role) or a role with the global CREATE INTEGRATION privilege can execute this SQL command.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-storage-integration.html

Try the following to act as an accountadmin, if you have the role granted:

```sql
use role accountadmin
```